# Javascript function syntax needs explanation

Tags: javascript

```
return this.foo("abc",function(){
                           //do something
                      });
```

Can some one tell me what does the above line do?
THanks

Comment: If you're new, what tutorial or book are you learning from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It grabs a reference to `this`, which might be the DOM Window, a DOM element, or any other JavaScript object depending on how and where the above code is being run.
2. It (skipping ahead) prepares a new anonymous `Function` that `//does something`.
3. It attempts to invoke a method `foo` on object `this`, passing in two parameters `"abc"` and said anonymous `Function`.

Very often when you see code that passes along an anonymous function (e.g. `function(){ ... }`), it is in fact holding on to that function in order to execute it not right away but at some later point in time, such as in response to a click event or a timer.

Answer (score 1):

It calls the function referenced by `this.foo` and passes two parameters: The [**string**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) `"abc"` and an anonymous [**function**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) `function(){ //do something}`. It then `return`s the result.

It is equivalent to:

```
var a = "abc";
var b = function(){ 
    //do something
};
return this.foo(a, b);
```

[Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) are first class objects in JS so you can pass them around like any other value.

---

I recommend to have a look at the [*MDC JavaScript guide*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide).

Answer (score 0):

looks like this.foo() is a function that returns something. so the return value is, what this.foo() returns.

Answer (score 0):

calls an instance method that gets as parameters a string and a function.

Answer (score 0):

It will return (yeah, like it is in English) the returned result of a function `this.foo(...)` (in the most simple form, ithe function `this.foo(...)` return "something" then the code will return "something"). The function `this.foo("abc", function(){...});` is itself a function which receives 2 arguments: A string "abc" and a function(). The function this.foo will do something and return "something" to return by the main function.
[x]